# Flutter: Could not generate user.g.dart with atribute geopoint

Tags: flutter, google-maps, serialization

I want to serialize user class but location generates error when I do flutter pub run build_runner build. How can I resolve it?

**user class**

```
 ...
 part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class UserData {
  final String uid;
  late final String name;
  final String surname;
  final List<Location> location;

  UserData(
      {required this.uid,
      required this.name,
      required this.surname,
      required this.location});

  factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json); 
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Location {
  String locationName;
  GeoPoint point;

  Location({required this.locationName, required this.point});
  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$LocationFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LocationToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: Have you added JSON annotations for `GeoPoint` class as well ?

Comment: No, how can add it?

Comment: Just like how you have added json annotations and `toJson` and `fromJson` methods for other two classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
location.g.dart
```

You may have to manually add the following code within `_$LocationFromJson{}`

```
point: json['geopoint'] as GeoPoint
```

Comment: Why? It is supposed to be added automatically by the builder.